# How to turn several HTML files into PDFs - pdfkit

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

In Python3 and using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I need to transform several .HTML files into .PDF files - I just want to turn the text that appears on the screen into a PDF (not the HTML code)

I used the Python-PDFKit: HTML to PDF wrapper and first installed it:

```
pip install pdfkit
```

and in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Here are two examples of .[HTML files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JkDIm51LHBkMF4XkwMTrF5uhYGBc7vZ4?usp=sharing)

The Python script to transform all the .HTML files is this:

```
import os
import pdfkit

# Directory where the HTML files are located
os.chdir("/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/chat_multiple_pdfs/TRANSFERENCIA")

diretorio_html = '/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/chat_multiple_pdfs/TRANSFERENCIA'

# List all files in the folder
arquivos_na_pasta = os.listdir(diretorio_html)

# Filter only HTML files
arquivos_html = [arquivo for arquivo in arquivos_na_pasta if arquivo.endswith('.html')]

# Enconding 
options = {
    'encoding': "UTF-8"
}

# Iterate in each file and turn into PDF
for arquivo_html in arquivos_html:
    nome_pdf = arquivo_html.replace(".html", ".pdf")
    with open(arquivo_html) as f:
        pdfkit.from_file(f, nome_pdf, options=options)
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_html_pdf.py", line 24, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_file(f, nome_pdf, options=options)
  File "/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/chat_multiple_pdfs/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 51, in from_file
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/chat_multiple_pdfs/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 201, in to_pdf
    self.handle_error(exit_code, stderr)
  File "/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/chat_multiple_pdfs/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 155, in handle_error
    raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

Please, does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Just a comment: Underneath, this uses `wkhtmltopdf`, which doesn't have good support for modern html/css. Beware of this if you're seeing visual problems.

Comment: Thanks @KJ with 'enable-local-file-access': None it worked. But some .PDF files were not correct - it looks like a TXT or corrupted file

Comment: Thank you very much @Kalnode And would you suggest another tool or methodology?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves Look into modern testing/browser-automation technologies like Playwright, Puppeteer, etc. The primary thing is they render a webpage as if it were a human-user using a browser. There's ways to output to PDF. Only question I have with these technologies is whether the PDF output can be "actual-text" or is it just "screenshot-images-inside-a-PDF" (not ideal).

Comment: Protocol error usually means there are some CSS tags or variables that PDFKit doesn't understand

Answer (score 0):

PDFkit usually needs a lot of cleanup to ensure your HTML code doesn't use modern CSS. You are better off using WeasyPrint, and I can definitely help you with it if you run into issues.